# Does use of memory with timing CL=10 instead of Apple used CL=11 slow my Mac down?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory

After reading [Why is 8GB, Ballistix 204-pin SODIMM, DDR3 PC3-12800 memory module showing as not compatible with Macbook Pro mid 2012?](http://forum.crucial.com/t5/Apple-Mac-Memory/Crucial-Ballistix-Sport-not-supported/td-p/133907) on the Crucial forum, and the response from Crucial:

> use our Apple branded Crucial memory

which doesn't explain the why it is not compatible,

I am curious whether memory modules that use different (lower) timings than Apple's modules with CL11 timing:

1. Will the Crucial Ballistix BX Sport CL10 [BLS8G3N18AES4CEU/BLS2C8G3N18AES4CEU] modules work?
2. And what will be the performance penalty or benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Crucial Ballistix Sport memory modules with **CL=10** timing **do work**.

The results of an **Xbench** 1.3 "**Memory Test**":

1. Hynix **CL=11**: **618.25**
2. Crucial **CL=10**: **699.12**

The not by Crucial recommended memory modules perform **13% faster** then Apple's factory default modules in this Mac.

---

Benchmarking performed on a 15" MacBook Pro (Mid 2012, MD103xx/A, MacBookPro9,1) with 2 modules of identical memory:

1. Apple default Hynix HMT325S6CFR8C-PB (PC3-12800S (DDR3-1600)
2. Crucial Ballistix Sport BLS2C8G3N18AES4CEU (PC3-14900 (DDR3-1866))

---

Detailed results:

1. Hynix

   - Memory Test: **618.25**
   - System: 679.54
   - Allocate: 2388.91 (8.77 Malloc/sec)
   - Fill: 414.93 (20174.73 MB/sec)
   - Copy: 630.47 (13022.12 MB/sec)
   - Stream: 567.11
   - Copy: 569.11 (11768.32 MB/sec)
   - Scale: 571.98 (11817.02 MB/sec)
   - Add: 568.58 (12112.06 MB/sec)
   - Triad: 558.29 (11943.20 MB/sec)
2. Crucial

   - Memory Test: **699.12**
   - System: 699.53
   - Allocate: 2327.00 (8.55 Malloc/sec)
   - Fill: 435.50 (21174.97 MB/sec)
   - Copy: 639.94 (13217.72 MB/sec)
   - Stream: 698.71
   - Copy: 689.46 (14240.61 MB/sec)
   - Scale: 695.49 (14368.67 MB/sec)
   - Add: 716.26 (15257.79 MB/sec)
   - Triad: 694.24 (14851.47 MB/sec)

Answer (score 0):

the cl of the sport is not 9 but 10.

To work the voltage is crucial, the 1,5 volt will give problems, the 1,35 volt will mostly work fine